# When a data model becomes a data nightmare

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

I am revising a data model for an educational company. So not your straightforward retail or finance model.

Problem is the company want to use the datawarehouse to produce listing reports, the kind of reports that should normally be produced by the Education Management System (EMS).

Reports like class lists, detailed learner information reports, guardian contact, work, and financial information, academic reports.

My argument thus far has been that a datawarehouse houses an analytical data model used to data analytics. Not a reporting model for an education management system with a for more complex relational database.

[image]

The current model has (forgive the crude diagram) snow flaked completely out of control in such a way that reporting and analytical tools are struggling to interpret it. The warehouse is starting to resemble the RDMS model more and more. There are so many relationships between Dimensions in order to keep data together.

Some of the tables contains so much unnecessary attributes that have no analytical value and purely exist for a listing report.

**I need some opinions/criticism (possibly as good reference) regarding this approach  so I can better explain the problem to a business who is oblivious to the concept of data modelling. I need to make them understand that butchering the DW to handle detailed reporting is going to end badly for them.**

Comment: Feel Free To Be Honest. LoL.

Comment: Really the only way to make the business understand is communicate how any future change or enhancement is going to take longer and longer (due to having to navigate around technical debt and having to avoid risk of breaking existing reports). That's the only thing the business understands - time and money. I completely agree that low latency operational reporting is usually best served out of the source system or a read only replica of it.

Comment: Funny enough the EMS currently have over 70 listing reports currently using the EMS's DB as its source. The EMS uses SQL Always On, which means report use a read-only DB as its source while the EMS uses the Primary DB as its source. Thus having no impact on the EMS's ability to perform DML duties.

Comment: It is quite common for a data warehouse to have a full-fidelity "staging" layer in addition to one or more simplified reporting models.  And you can use this layered approach to prevent your analytical data models from becoming overly complex.